# HTTP Request - Delete JSON file key in Firebase with Axios

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I have a firebase database setup with an orders.json file created.  I already have it setup to where I can post an order to the json file from a javascript project, and then firebase assigns a unique key which looks like "-LKx1RmbvyruM8-5S2mo".  I would like to delete a single order based off of that unique identifier key via http request and query params without deleting the entire orders.json file. I'm also using authentication, so my request would look like this:

axios.delete('https://myproject-37b7d.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=mytoken')

This would of course delete the entire json file which I do not want.  Would I put the unique key in the url query params somehow?  Or in the axios config?  I figured out how to console log it in a GET request via the .get().then(res => console.log(res.data["-LKx1RmbvyruM8-5S2mo"]))

I tried reading through firebase's api and not many good examples.  Any help is much appreciated[image: ![firebase database]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjBxL.png) 
u

Answer (score 1):

Due to firebase database is a simple json-like object, and single order is an object too, with its own link, I simply make a delete request like that:

```
removeOrderHandler = (orderId) =>{
    axios.delete("/orders/" + orderId +".json?auth=" + this.props.token)
```